# Accessing Corda node shell via SSH when running Docker locally

Tags: ssh, docker-compose, dockerfile, corda

I set up the nodes (partya, partyb, partyc, notary) from the "samples/cordapp-example" with docker-compose (Dockerform). They are all running corda.jar (within their containers). It seems to have an issue with ssh communication: I constantly get errors "connection refused". The documentation/the code seems to be outdated.

[image: errors]

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow!

You may wish to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 

You may find this question is slightly more suited to the SuperUser site.  Good luck with your quest for answers!

Comment: Corda questions are on topic for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Dockerform` task doesn't recognize [the `node.conf` option that enables SSH access](https://docs.corda.net/shell.html#enabling-ssh-access) (and the docs seem a tad incomplete on the subject). A few steps to work around this:

1. Make sure that each node (including the notary) defined in a `Dockerform`-type `deployNodes` has an entry for `p2pAddress` (instead of `p2pPort`) that looks like this: "name-of-docker-container:port-number" (where name-of-docker-container is the lowercase name of each node folder; e.g. `partya:10004`). Run `deployNodes`.
2. Edit the `docker-compose.yml` file generated by `deployNodes` so that each service exposes some additional ports (for allowing p2p communication and allowing ssh access to the node shell) and binds them all to the host machine - e.g.

```
version: '3'
services:
  notary:
    build: /Users/user/myapp/build/nodes/Notary
    ports:
    - 10003:10003
    - 8051:8051 # add port here
    - 9051:9051 # add port here
    - 2222:2222 # add port here
  partya:
    build: /Users/user/myapp/build/nodes/PartyA
    ports:
    - 10004:10004 # edit port
    - 8052:8052 # add port here
    - 9052:9052 # add port here
    - 2223:2223 # add port here

# keep on doing this for additional nodes
```

3. Modify the last line of the `run-corda.sh` files generated by the `deployNodes` task so that it reads: `java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar ${CORDA_HOME}/corda.jar --sshd --sshd-port <insert-here-port-number> 2>&1` (where `<insert-here-port-number>` is one of the new port numbers you've exposed in the services in the `docker-compose.yml` file)
4. Run `docker-compose up --build -d`
5. Run `ssh localhost -p <insert-here-host-port-number> -l user1` (where  is the port number you've defined on step #2 to allow ssh access).